# A backup tool which can upload to FTP

Tags: backup, ftp, language, filenames, job-scheduler

I'm now using Cobian Backup Gravity for this purpose but it has some issues:
- It doesn't support Cyrillic / Unicode file names in archives (it says in the FAQ it does though)

[image: file names]

Now I don't have enough free space to create a backup locally which then should be transferred to a remote store. I even have enabled archive split option and it doesn't help.

[image: Options]

I would like a backuper can do:

- Full file backups
- Compressing
- Send notifications about successful or failed attempts to backup
- Schedule. I would like to set it to do backups at night
- Upload to remote FTP as well as having a local copy

Comment: Welcome kseen! What is your price range?  I can recommend a tool called SyncBackPro (https://www.2brightsparks.com/), but I have not tested it with Cyrillic characters in filenames.  It meets all your other requirements quite well.

Answer (score 1):

For me Cobian Backup 11 can be installed in Russian language, and it compresses files with cyrillic names without problems to zip or 7z archives.

Also, try configuring the system locale to the correct one. You can find a lot of tutorials how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend you the free software personal backup:

[Check out the homepage here](http://personal-backup.rathlev-home.de/index-e.html)

It should fit to all your requirements.